# rdirichlet distribution isn't working in R

Tags: r, dirichlet

I am attempting to run some code I wrote over a year ago and for some reason it is not working this time.  Previously I had the matrix variables alpha and prob typed into R.  However this time I am importing them as csv files so it's easier for me to modify them with each itteration.  I'm currently running R x64 2.12.2. I loaded gtools, splines and stat4 packages.

```
alpha <- read.csv("AlphaOriginal.csv", header = FALSE)
prior <- array(0,c(45,45))
for (j in 1:45) prior[j,] <- rdirichlet(1,alpha[j,])

prob <- read.csv("ProbOriginal.csv", header = FALSE)
data <- array(0,c(45,45))
for (i in 1:45) data[i,] <- rmultinom(1,1,prob[i,])

posterior <- data%*%prior

write.table(posterior, file = "PosteriorOriginal.csv", row.names = FALSE, na = "", col.names = FALSE, sep = ",")
```

After the rdirichlet line I get the following error.

```
Error in rgamma (1*n, alpha) : invalid arguments
```

Does anyone know what this error means and how to fix it? Thx

Comment: why are you running a 4 year old r build?

Comment: You didn't provide a minimal reproducible example. What is e.g. `alpha`?

Comment: The four year old build is what we were using in my statistics class at my university which is why I am still using it.

Comment: For the Alpha values it's a 45x45 matrix with probability values in each node.  The values range from 0 - 0.999999. The program seems to be reading these values in fine.  It reproduces the 45x45 matrix in R exactly as it is in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the 'rdirichlet' help page you will find that the 'alpha' argument must be a vector, not a data.frame. So you should instead do:

```
rdirichlet(1, unlist(alpha[j,]))
```

Comment: Will this work if my alpha values are a matrix, not just a single line vector?  From what I can find on 'unlist', it will flatten my matrix into a single line which will affect my calculations.  Is there something similar to 'unlist' for matrices?

Comment: I have already assumed alpha to be a matrix but in you code you wrote alpha[j,], which would correspond to the j-th row of the matrix.